# Android: Add Watermark to Bitmap in Async Task

Tags: java, android, bitmap, watermark

I would like to add Watermark to my Bitmap. Since the bitmap is retrieved from server, I need to add the watermark in the Async Task. I have tried to use bellow code:

```
int w = src.getWidth();
int h = src.getHeight();
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, 0, 0, null);
```

However, I got

> NullPointerException error

What is wrong? Is it not possible to add watermark to an image in Async Task? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post all of your `AsyncTask` code and also logcat showing the NPE

Comment: Update your answer with the stack trace to show there the NullPointer was. My guess would be mContext..